# Change XML Namespace of DataMember

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have two `DataContract`s which I am serializing to XML using a `DataContractSerializer`.

I specify different namespace for the two different `DataContract`s however, there is a `DataMember` in each `DataContract` which is of the same POD type. This POD is in a different c# namespace.

I would like to know if there is a way of specifying the namespace to use for this `DataMember` depending on which containing type it belongs to.

For example:

```
namespace NamespaceShared
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public sealed class SharedType
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int ValueOne { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int ValueTwo { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace NamespaceOne
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using NamespaceShared;

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.one")]
    public sealed class DataContractOne
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        //[SomeNamespaceAttribute("http://namespace.one")]
        private SharedType SharedValue { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace NamespaceTwo
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using NamespaceShared;

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.two")]
    public sealed class DataContractTwo
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        //[SomeNamespaceAttribute("http://namespace.two")]
        private SharedType SharedValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something which would provide the functionality of `SomeNamespaceAttribute` in the code above.

Note: I'm not looking for suggestions on how better to organise my `DataContract`s because unfortunately I'm refactoring legacy code and the XML format can't be changed.

Comment: Is it an option to switch to the XmlSerializer? The XmlElementAttribute has an option to specify the namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately not. But thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to change the namespace? What are you trying to change?

Comment: I'm working with some legacy code and don't want to make changes to existing XML schemas. However I would like to reuse some of the existing objects in a new namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContractSerializer` does not expose as fine grained control over the XML generation, so this sort of attribute is not inherently available.  However, you could subclass the shared class (assuming you can get rid of the `sealed` access modifier), with two different `DataContract` attributes with different namespaces.

```
namespace NamespaceShared
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    public class SharedType
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int ValueOne { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int ValueTwo { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.one")]
    public class SharedTypeOne : SharedType
    {
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.two")]
    public class SharedTypeTwo : SharedType
    {
    }
}

namespace NamespaceOne
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using NamespaceShared;

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.one")]
    public sealed class DataContractOne
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        private SharedTypeOne SharedValue { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace NamespaceTwo
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using NamespaceShared;

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.two")]
    public sealed class DataContractTwo
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        private SharedTypeTwo SharedValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If all else fails, you could edit the raw XML coming out of the service using a technique similar to that which is used to change the auto-generated prefixes.  [This MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx) details the overall process.

Comment: Hasn't solved the problem but it's probably the correct answer.