# DataContractSerializer: SerializationException, 'EndElement' is not expected

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialise a small snippet of XML with the DataContractSerializer:

```
<iopbase:SoapFaultException xmlns:iopbase=""http://example.com/foo/"">
   <faultcode></faultcode>
   <faultstring>Hello World</faultstring>
</iopbase:SoapFaultException>
```

The problem is the DataContractSerializer doesn't 'see' the `<faultcode>` and `<faultstring>` elements and I get the following Exception:

```
SerializationException: 'EndElement' 'SoapFaultException' from namespace 
'http://example.com/foo/' is not expected. Expecting element 'faultcode'.
```

Here's a stripped down bit of code to replicate the issue:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/foo/")]
public class SoapFaultException
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string faultcode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string faultstring { get; set; }
}

var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(@"
<iopbase:SoapFaultException xmlns:iopbase=""http://example.com/foo/"">
  <faultcode></faultcode>
  <faultstring>Hello World</faultstring>
</iopbase:SoapFaultException>");

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SoapFaultException));
var e = (SoapFaultException) serializer.ReadObject(xml.CreateReader()); <- Exception Here
```

And finally, stack trace of the Exception.

```
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ThrowRequiredMemberMissingException(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 memberIndex, Int32 requiredIndex, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNames)
   at ReadSoapFaultExceptionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader reader)
   at XXX.Program.Main() in C:\Git\XXX\Program.cs:line 161
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the exception is that the namespaces of the elements `<faultcode>` and `<faultstring>` are inconsistent with the data contract.

On the one hand, in your XML, the root element is in the `xmlns:iopbase="http://example.com/foo/"` namespace but its child elements are not in any namespace, lacking the `xmlns:` prefix.  On the other hand, by adding `[DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/foo/")]` to `SoapFaultException` you are specifying that the `SoapFaultException` root element *as well as its child elements* are to appear in the specified namespace.  And since the XML elements are not in this namespace, they are not deserialized successfully.

To confirm this, if I serialize out an instance of your type, setting the namespace prefix `xmlns:iopbase="http://example.com/foo/"`, I get:

```
<iopbase:SoapFaultException xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com/foo/" xmlns:iopbase="http://example.com/foo/">
  <iopbase:faultcode></iopbase:faultcode>
  <iopbase:faultstring>Hello World</iopbase:faultstring>
</iopbase:SoapFaultException>
```

Using the code

```
var test = new SoapFaultException { faultcode = "", faultstring = "Hello World" };

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SoapFaultException));
var doc = new XDocument();
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, test);
}
// Add the iopbase prefix for clarity
doc.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "iopbase", "http://example.com/foo/"));
Debug.WriteLine(doc);
```

To solve the problem, ideally you would like to be able to specify data member namespaces independently of the overall data contract namespace, but unfortunately the data contract serializer [doesn't support that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067180/change-xml-namespace-of-datamember).  Instead, you have the following options:

- You could split your `SoapFaultException` into a class hierarchy and specify a different namespace for each level in the hierarchy, placing the most derived type in the root element's namespace like so:

  ```
  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
  public abstract class SoapFaultExceptionBase
  {
      [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
      public string faultcode { get; set; }

      [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
      public string faultstring { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/foo/")]
  public class SoapFaultException : SoapFaultExceptionBase
  {
  }
  ```
- You could leave your `SoapFaultException` in the empty namespace, and [construct your `DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404902(v=vs.110).aspx) with a supplied XML root element name and namespace:

  ```
  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
  public class SoapFaultException
  {
      [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
      public string faultcode { get; set; }

      [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
      public string faultstring { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  And then do:

  ```
  var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SoapFaultException), "SoapFaultException", "http://example.com/foo/");
  var e = (SoapFaultException)serializer.ReadObject(xml.CreateReader());
  ```

Comment: it seems obvious now you point out the child elements do not belong to a namespace! I used your abstract and sub class suggestion. Thank you very much!